# How can I stop a Slider from changing its value when the user wants to drag it?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, events, slider

Take this scenario:

- I have 5 sliders (slider 1, slider 2, slider 3, slider 4, and slider 5).
- I can give each slider a value from 0 to 100, but...
- They must share up to a maximum sum of 100 if you add all of their values together.
- IE if slider 1 is 50 and slider 2 is 50, all other sliders must be 0.
- IE if slider 1 is 100, all other sliders must be 0.
- IE if slider 5 is 90, slider 2 is 5, and slider 3 is 5, all other sliders must be 0.

I want to make it so that if I increase a slider, I cannot go past the maximum if the sum of all the sliders is at the maximum, but I would also like it to not be able to actually process an event in that case. Specifically, if I try to drag a Slider, I do not want it to actually be able to change that value under those circumstances. Right now, I have the following code, but this will actually decrement the value if it goes over, which is not the same as constricting it from changing the value when the user tries to drag it:

```
    public class MaximumSliderGroup
    {

        List<Slider> m_sliders = new List<Slider>();

        Grid m_containerGrid;
        int m_startColumn;
        int m_startRow;
        int m_startColumnSpan;
        int m_startRowSpan;
        double m_maximum;

        public MaximumSliderGroup(Grid containerGrid, int startColumn, int startRow, int startColumnSpan, int startRowSpan, double maximum)
        {
            m_containerGrid = containerGrid;
            m_startColumn = startColumn;
            m_startRow = startRow;
            m_startColumnSpan = startColumnSpan;
            m_startRowSpan = startRowSpan;
            m_maximum = maximum;
        }

        public void AddNewSlider(bool createNewRow)
        {
            Slider slider = new Slider();
            slider.Maximum = m_maximum;
            slider.Minimum = 0;
            Grid.SetRow(slider, m_startRow + m_sliders.Count);
            Grid.SetColumn(slider, m_startColumn + m_sliders.Count);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(slider, m_startColumnSpan);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(slider, m_startRowSpan);
            if (createNewRow)
            {
                RowDefinition rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
                rowDefinition.Height = GridLength.Auto;
                m_containerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
            }
            m_containerGrid.Children.Add(slider);
            slider.ValueChanged += slider_ValueChanged;
            m_sliders.Add(slider);
        }

        void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            Slider senderAsSlider = (Slider)sender;
            double count = 0;
            foreach (Slider slider in m_sliders)
            {
                count += slider.Value;
            }
            if (count > m_maximum)
            {
                senderAsSlider.Value--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: Just figured out a workaround that looks acceptable by my standards. It may not stop the event from happening, but it doesn't flicker the value when you keep trying to drag it due to the rounding.

```
    public class MaximumSliderGroup
    {

        List<Slider> m_sliders = new List<Slider>();
        List<Label> m_labels = new List<Label>();

        Grid m_containerGrid;
        Grid m_subContainerGrid;
        int m_startColumn;
        int m_startRow;
        int m_startColumnSpan;
        int m_startRowSpan;
        double m_maximum;

        public MaximumSliderGroup(Grid containerGrid, int startColumn, int startRow, int startColumnSpan, int startRowSpan, double maximum)
        {
            // Set the properties.
            m_containerGrid = containerGrid;
            m_startColumn = startColumn;
            m_startRow = startRow;
            m_startColumnSpan = startColumnSpan;
            m_startRowSpan = startRowSpan;
            m_maximum = maximum;
            // Create a new sub-grid for sliders and labels at the specified location within the main grid.
            m_subContainerGrid = new Grid();
            Grid.SetRow(m_subContainerGrid, m_startRow);
            Grid.SetColumn(m_subContainerGrid, m_startColumn);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(m_subContainerGrid, m_startColumnSpan);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(m_subContainerGrid, m_startRowSpan);
            ColumnDefinition sliderColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
            sliderColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            m_subContainerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(sliderColumn);
            ColumnDefinition textBoxColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
            textBoxColumn.Width = GridLength.Auto;
            m_subContainerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(textBoxColumn);
            m_containerGrid.Children.Add(m_subContainerGrid);
        }

        public void AddNewSlider(bool createNewRow)
        {
            // Create a new slider, and add it to the sub-grid.
            Slider slider = new Slider();
            slider.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            slider.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            slider.Maximum = m_maximum;
            slider.Minimum = 0;
            if (createNewRow)
            {
                RowDefinition rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
                rowDefinition.Height = GridLength.Auto;
                m_subContainerGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
            }
            Grid.SetRow(slider, m_sliders.Count);
            Grid.SetColumn(slider, 0);
            slider.ValueChanged += slider_ValueChanged;
            m_sliders.Add(slider);
            m_subContainerGrid.Children.Add(slider);
            // Create a new label, and add it to the sub-grid.
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Content = "0";
            label.FontSize = 20;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetRow(label, m_labels.Count);
            Grid.SetColumn(label, 1);
            m_labels.Add(label);
            m_subContainerGrid.Children.Add(label);
        }

        void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            // Round the slider value.
            Slider senderAsSlider = (Slider)sender;
            double count = 0;
            foreach (Slider slider in m_sliders)
            {
                count += slider.Value;
            }
            if (count > m_maximum)
            {
                senderAsSlider.Value = Math.Round(senderAsSlider.Value - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                if (senderAsSlider.Value != 0)
                {
                    senderAsSlider.Value = Math.Round(senderAsSlider.Value);
                }
            }
            // Update the relevant label.
            foreach (Label label in m_labels)
            {
                if (Grid.GetRow(label) == Grid.GetRow(senderAsSlider))
                {
                    label.Content = senderAsSlider.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you skip the current slider (sender) in the ValueChanged handler to prevent a loop?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Irrelevant, but, once you decrement the value once from one event change, the value changed event will come in once more, and at that point in time, there is no other change in value since it will not decrement it again since it will be below the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this my friend is why they created coersion.

So, what you want to do is create a multibinding from a value you control to each of the sliders. Then you want to coerce on those values to control their values.

Step 1:
Rip out all the UI code from your class.

Step 2:
Create a data object that will store off values.

Step 3:
Multibind those values to a single total value.

Step 4:
Coerce the individual values whenever the multibinding changes.

Step 5:
Create the UI class

Step 6:
Every time you add a slider to the UI class, add a value to the data object and bind to it.

Comment: Will this work if I want to round slider values to integral values?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I just got it working the way I want it to, so I won't be going down this route, however, its nice to know about this feature. Thanks for the information.